# HTML <select> attributes size="0" vs size="1"

Tags: html, html-select

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) reference of `<select>` element:

> **`size`** If the control is presented as a scrolled list box, this attribute represents the number of rows in the list that should be visible at one time. Browsers are not required to present a select element as a scrolled list box. **The default value is 0.**

In the following example, the presentation of the default, `size="0"` and `size="1"` look exactly the same. Are there any differences in terms of functionality or anything else?

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>

<select size="0">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>

<select size="1">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MDN is incorrect. The value of `size` defaults to `1` for single-value selection, and `4` for `multiple` value selection. `0` is not a valid value and so it would be treated the same as the default.

From [section 4.10.7 *The select element*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-select-element) in the WHATWG HTML specification (emphasis mine):

> The `size` attribute gives the number of options to show to the user. The `size` attribute, if specified, **must have a value that is a valid non-negative integer greater than zero**.

> The display size of a select element is the result of applying the rules for parsing non-negative integers to the value of element's `size` attribute, if it has one and parsing it is successful. If applying those rules to the attribute's value is not successful, or if the `size` attribute is absent, then **the element's display size is 4 if the element's `multiple` content attribute is present, and `1` otherwise.**